# Spatie Media Library - file is not copied to the Laravel storage

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail, media-library, laravel-package

I have set up a fresh Laravel 10. Use Laravel Sail for my environment. I added the basic Spatie Media Library package. In my TestModel I have implemented HasMedia and added the InteractsWithMedia Trait.

**My blade**

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('test.upload', $test->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="image" name="image" class=">
</form>
```

**My Controller**

```php
    public function upload(Request $request, Test $test)
    {        
        if($request->has('image')) {            
            $test->addMedia(($request->image))->toMediaCollection('images');
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

I do not receive an error message after the upload and am redirected back as desired. No error is written in the error log either. I should now be able to see the new file in my `storage/app/public` folder. But I don't see it. Now I ask myself why? **Could it be due to the use of Sail?**

**Note 1:**
I have also tried skipping the form and copying a test image from the storage folder. Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. I now suspect that the error may either be in my Sail environment or perhaps in the new Spatie package (*"spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^11.0.0"*).

**Note 2:** I have written a file with the Laravel Storage package to test if there is something wrong with the permissions. And it works!

```php
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('local')->put('example.txt', 'Contents');
```

**dd( $test->addMediaFromRequest('image')->toMediaCollection() );**

```
Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media {#1273 ▼ // app/Http/Controllers/TestController.php:67
  #connection: null
  #table: "media"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: array:11 [▼
    "name" => "image-2024-01-08 21-05-00"
    "file_name" => "image-2024-01-08-21-05-00.png"
    "disk" => "public"
    "conversions_disk" => "public"
    "collection_name" => "default"
    "mime_type" => "image/png"
    "size" => 170175
    "custom_properties" => "[]"
    "generated_conversions" => "[]"
    "responsive_images" => "[]"
    "manipulations" => "[]"
  ]
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: array:4 [▶]
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: array:2 [▶]
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  +usesUniqueIds: false
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: []
  #streamChunkSize: 1048576
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that `$request->has('image')` is true? Try `dd($request->has('image')` in the start of your function.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes i checked it is true. but good point. thanks

Comment: OK. Have you tried [`addMediaFromRequest('image')`](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v11/api/adding-files#content-addmediafromrequest) instead of `addMedia`?

Comment: You should also check that the form you are sending from is set to multipart.

Comment: I would `dd($request->image)` and also try/catch around `$test->addMedia(($request->image))->toMediaCollection('images')`, it might be that multipart thing, like ceejayyoz says

Comment: @Second2None Thx for your comment. I use already the enctype. i updated my question and put my form to it.

Comment: @MartinTTS Actually, I'd check you have set it up correctly - also check its not being added to your actual public folder.

Comment: @Second2None I checked but i didnt found a problem. i really dont know what the problem is because i dindt recieve an error.